# Issue with tap over keyboard's return key for UIAlertView's UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput field iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uialertview, uialertviewdelegate

While tapping over keyboard's return key while entering value in `UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput` of a `UIAlertView` is triggering call to `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` `UIAlertViewDelegate` in iOS 8

In iOS 7 same `UIAlertViewDelegate`  call wasn't getting triggered in same conditions.

I am not sure if this is an issue in `iOS 8 or iOS 7`. But my code stopped functioning as per expectation iOS 8.

Code sample:

```
    #include "MPAMyViewController.h"

    static NSString *MPAPasswordConfirmationAlertTitle = @"Please confirm your password.";
    static NSString *MPAPasswordConfirmationAlertCancelButtonTitle = @"Cancel";
    static NSString *MPAPasswordConfirmationAlertOkButtonTitle = @"OK";
    static NSString *MPAPasswordConfirmationTextFieldPlaceholder = @"Enter Password";

    @interface MPAMyViewController () <UIAlertViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>

    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *errorFromRequest;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) UIAlertView *passwordAlertView;

    - (void)processRequest:(UITextField *)passwordTextField;

    @end

    @implementation MPAMyViewController

    - (IBAction)showPasswordConfirmationAlert:(id)sender {
        self.passwordAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:MPAPasswordConfirmationAlertTitle
                                                            message:self.errorFromRequest
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:MPAPasswordConfirmationAlertCancelButtonTitle
                                                  otherButtonTitles:MPAPasswordConfirmationAlertOkButtonTitle, nil];

        self.passwordAlertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput;

        UITextField *passwordTextField = [self.passwordAlertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        [passwordTextField becomeFirstResponder];
        passwordTextField.placeholder = MPAPasswordConfirmationTextFieldPlaceholder;
        passwordTextField.delegate = self;

        [self.passwordAlertView show];
    }


    #pragma mark - UIAlertViewDelegate

    - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
        NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

        if([title isEqualToString:MPAPasswordConfirmationAlertOkButtonTitle]) {
            UITextField *passwordTextField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
            [self processRequest:passwordTextField];
        }
    }


    #pragma mark - TextField Delegate

    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
        [self.passwordAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:self.passwordAlertView.firstOtherButtonIndex animated:YES];

        return YES;
    }

    - (void)processRequest:(UITextField *)passwordTextField {
        NSString *password = passwordTextField.text;

        // CODE: send request
    }

    @end
```

Comment: Not sure it is downvoted after 3 and half year.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with an UIAlertView Delegatemethod not getting called. I found out that UIAlertView is deprecated in iOS 8. You should use UIAlertController.

Answer (score 0):

Use UIAlertController to make it [compatible with iOS 8](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/09/05/uialertcontroller-changes-in-ios-8.html).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.
UIAlertController won't make any difference. The mentioned delegate alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex is still getting called.

Even I have to make it conditional because UIAlertController won't work for iOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

Using alertView , use the delegation and use any of the Delegate method of the UIAlertView .. You haven't set the delegate to you current view controller so try the code below

use the

```
 UIAlertView * alertView  = UIAlertView()
  viewDidLoad(){

 alertView.delegate = self
}
```

Using the above code you delegate methods will be invoked.

Comment: I am able to invoke delegate methods. Invoking delegate method is not an issue. What you have mentioned is already done in my code shared. 

The `alertView: clickedButtonAtIndex:` is getting invoked unneccessorily in iOS 8 on tap over return key from keyboard while entering value to input field on Alert view.

Answer (score 0):

Try below snippet of code.

```
#pragma mark - TextField Delegate

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {  
    return NO;
}
```

Note: If you are using above delegate for other text fields then write conditional code as per your requirement.